# jQuery table row filter - hide and show at the same time

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a table which contains a column with keywords and a select field (css class .filter) with options and values that correspond to those keywords.

It works fine until I change the select field to another option. With the following code everything is hidden obviously. But to add a .show() for every row before the hiding does not work (nothing gets hidden anymore). To show the selected rows after hiding does not work either.

```
$(".filter").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "all") {
            $("tbody").find("tr:not(:contains('"+$(this).val()+"'))").hide(); //hide everything except what contains the selected option

        } else {
            $("tbody").find("tr:hidden").show(); // reset the filter and show everything
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide all the rows then show only the filtered items

```
$("tbody").find("tr").hide().filter(":contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").show();
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, this looks neat and makes perfect sense to me, but it doesn't work for some reason unkown.

Comment: Hi and thanks again - I've found the mistake. Your line is working perfectly. More elegant than mine. Mistake was: i had two elements with that class name... stupid me.